# Advanced File permission and how to read them correctly

Tags: linux, permissions

```bsh
alisto@ubuntu:/projects/solarproj$ \ls -al
total 32
drwxrwsr-t 3 root   solarproj 4096 Dec 8 16:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root      4096 Dec 8 15:29 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 boband boband    802  Dec 8 15:44 bearings.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 boband solarproj 101  Dec 8 15:43 controller.c
drwxrwSr-x 2 alisto solarproj 4096 Dec 8 15:40 old
-------rwx 1 alisto solarproj 19   Dec 8 14:08 power
-rw-r--r-- 1 alisto solarproj 81   Dec 8 15:44 schedule.txt
-rw----r-- 1 boband solarproj 576  Dec 8 15:58 temp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alisto solarproj 24   Dec 8 16:02 temp.sym      ->  ../solarproj/temp
```

Both users are in the solarproj group

1. Can Bob change the content in the file `schedule.txt`? Why?

   If I am reading this correctly the answer is no, because group is set to only read.
2. Can Alice remove the file `controller.c`? Why?

   The file gives read and write permission, but because of the sticky bit she can't remove it/not so sure her
3. Which users can read the file `power`? Why?

   All the other users that are not part of group or Alisto
4. Why can Alice, but not Bob list the content in directory old?

   Because of the S on the group permission the x doesn't exist
5. Can Alice read the file `temp.sym`? Why?

   No, because she is not permitted.

I don't know if my answers are correct and would love if someone could correct my wrong answers and help me a bit. I would love to test it out and see for myself, but my vm is not working and I need to study for upcoming test in a few days try again!

Comment: is this a homework question or something like that? do you have any idea what the answers might be?

Comment: Should we assume Alice=alisto and Bob=boband?

Comment: I have tidied and formatted your question. However there seems to be bits I don't understand. Are they paste errors, if so then remove them, else edit to make them clear. There are "/not so sure her" and "try again!"

Comment: Who is bob and alice, you have two other people in the code.

Comment: I don't thing this is the place for this type of question, we are not here to be your computer. However as a teacher answer 5 does not say why: you said "it is not permitted, because it is not permitted". (also re-consider 4)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, because it is off topic: it is simply asking us to be the OP's computer, and reply with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a permission is displayed using the `ls` command, it follows a certain structure. Lets take a look at the an example:

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

The **first** character indicates the type of file and is called the *file descriptor*, **next three characters** indicate the permissions for the user who created the file, the **next set of three characters** indicate the permissions for the user's group, and the **last three characters** indicate the permissions for everyone else.

In this example:

- the **first** character, known as the file descriptor, indicates the type of file. In this case of `-rw-rw-r--`, it is the dash at the beginning.
- the **next three characters** indicate the permissions for the user who created the file. In this case of `-rw-rw-r--`, it is `rw-`.
- the **next three characters after that** indicate the permissions for the previously-mentioned user's group.
- the **last three characters** show the permissions for everyone else.

The first character, or the file descriptor, a single dash (`-`), shows that this is just a normal file. On the other hand, if this was the permissions for the directory, it would be a single `d` instead. A non-comprehensive list of possible values for the file descriptor:

- `d` - a directory
- `-` - a "normal" file
- `l` - a symbolic link
- `s` - a UNIX socket
- `p` - a pipeline

The other three sets of three characters follow the structure `[read][write][exec]`, where each bracket holds one character.

So, in our example of `-rw-rw-r--`:

- the permissions for the user who created the file are `rw-`. So that user can read and write to the file, but not execute it.
- the permissions for the user's group are also `rw-`, which means that the user's group can read and write to it, too.
- the permissions for everyone else are `r--`; this means that everyone else can only read the file, not write to it or execute it.

So, for your questions:

> Can Bob change the content in the file schedule.txt? Why?
>
> If I am reading this correctly the answer is no because group is set to only read

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 alisto solarproj 81   Dec 8 15:44 schedule.txt
```

You are correct. `boband` is part of the `solarproj` group, so his permissions are `r--`, meaning that he may only read the file, not change it.

> Can Alice remove the file controller.c? Why?
>
> The file gives read and write permission but because of the sticky bit she cant remove it/not so sure her

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 boband solarproj 101  Dec 8 15:43 controller.c
```

Yes, she can. Her permissions are `rw-` since she is part of the solarproj group, so the can change the file, which includes deleting it.

> Which users can read the file power? Why?
>
> All the other users that are not part of group or Alisto

```
-------rwx 1 alisto solarproj 19   Dec 8 14:08 power
```

Again, correct. Only a user that 1) isn't in the `solarproj` group and 2) isn't `alisto` will be able to read, change, or execute that file.

> Why can Alice but not Bob list the content in directory old?
>
> Because of the S on the group permission the x doesn't exist

```
drwxrwSr-x 2 alisto solarproj 4096 Dec 8 15:40 old
```

Nope. The `S` means the the file **is** executable **and** the setguid bit is set.

> Can Alice read the file temp.sym? Why?
>
> No because she is not permitted

```
-rw----r-- 1 boband solarproj 576  Dec 8 15:58 temp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alisto solarproj 24   Dec 8 16:02 temp.sym      ->  ../solarproj/temp
```

Correct. `temp.sym` points the file `temp`; while `alisto` can read from `temp.sym`, because it points to `temp`, which `alisto` **cannot** read from, she will be denied permission.